# Homotopy continuations for solving systems of equations over a finite field

Tags: systems-of-equations, finite-fields, homotopy-theory

A way of solving systems of polynomial equations over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is using homotopy continuation. Roughly speaking this method uses a homotopy that starts from some system of equations of which the solutions are known and goes to the the system of equations that we want to solve. By numerically tracking the solutions as the system of equations changes into the system we want to solve one can find its solutions.

To me, this method seems useless for solving polynomial systems of equations over finite fields. For starters, I don't think that finite fields (or their extensions) have the topological structure that is needed for the concept of homotopy to make sense.

Is the method of homotopy continuation completely doomed in this context?

Comment: Homotopy continuation is a numeric algorithm, so I have to ask. Does it make sense to apply *any* numeric algorithm to find solutions of systems of equation over finite fields? I really think finite fields are restricted to symbolic computations only.

Comment: i think a modified version of this problem suited for MO.

Comment: @Integral This question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158261/numerical-analysis-over-finite-fields is about using numerical methods over finite fields.

Comment: @Turbo What kind of modification do you suggest?

Comment: @WardBeullens I think fact that finite fields have no topological structure is false http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243596/manifold-over-a-finite-field.